# ActiveJDBC Instrumentation: Unable to instrument the model classes which are in Jar

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, activejdbc

I am using activejdbc 1.4.9. I created one jar (using maven) which has two ActiveJDBC Model Classes. I added the jar to the  application. Application has three more model classes. When I compile and try to run the application (gradle based), activejdbc is instrumenting only 3 classes which are in application but not instrumenting the classes which are in jar. When I try to write the data into the two models which are in jar, It is throwing exception as

org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Failed to retrieve metadata from DB. Are you sure table exists in DB ?

Now I have certain doubts. Please help me to resolve and understand few things.

1. How instrumentation happens ?
2. When we create a jar, will it include instrumented classes ?
3. Why it is throwing this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing this error in case classes have not been instrumented. This means that before placing your model classes into a jar file, you need to instrument them. Does not matter which build method you use though. This http://javalite.io/instrumentation  explains what is instrumentation and how to do  it. Instrumentation does not create jars, it merely adds some byte code into your classes. In all scenarios you need:

1. Write code :)
2. Compile
3. Instrument

after this, you can do any of the following:

- run app using class files in the file system
- package class files into jar file and use that on your classpath
- package jar file into a larger app (WAR, EAR, RAR, etc.) and deploy your app

making sense?

Comment: It didn't work. The steps i followed are 1. mvn compile 2. mvn activejdbc-instrumentation:instrument 3. mvn package. Then I added this jar to application. Still it is throwing exception as org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: failed to find metamodel for class X.  Are you sure that a corresponding table  exists in DB?

Comment: I'm confident that something is wrong with your build, and you recompile classes after instrumentation (there by erasing it). 
Here is a [Simple Maven Example](https://github.com/javalite/simple-example) and here is a [Simple Gradle Exmple](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc-gradle), either one should help you

Comment: Thanks for reply ipolevoy. Build scripts are exactly as same as you specified in examples. It created the jar and some of the static methods were added to Model Classes(verified trough decomplier). After adding this jar to the application, it is still throwing the application.

Comment: ipolevoy, If i am running through intellij, it is working fine. If i build shadow jar and run it, it is not working

Comment: @SanthoshTangudu, you obviously have a problem with your build. You run non-instrumented classes in your app. If you are not running java 8, you can try [Dynamic Instrumentation](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/tree/master/activejdbc-instrumentation). This way, you can skip static instrumentation. Otherwise, you need to find why you are  including non-instrumented models on your classspath

Comment: As you said, there is a problem with build script only. We found the problem and fixed the problem. Thank you very much for helping us to solve the problem